# Ms project, how to calculate difference between actual duration and duration?

Tags: ms-project

Ms project, how to calculate difference between actual duration and duration ?
i mean for example:

if any resource finish the task before the actual finish date , how can i calculate this overtime ????

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to PM:SE. It is not clear what you are asking. Can you specify what value you are trying to calculate please? I.e. the difference between which MS-Project fields.

Comment: Is your question "if a resource finishes a task early, how do I manage that in the project plan"?

Comment: If the task finishes early, that isn't overtime, it is variance. Any difference between predicted and actual is variance.  If you are careful to never ever change the "finish" date, but only change the "Actual finish" date, then MS Project will calculate the variance for you.

Answer (score 0):

Baseline the project and insert the Duration Variance column. The values work as a timeline where 0 equals the baseline finish and a negative value means it finished early, because it's before the baselined finish (0).